# SQLdelight drop all tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I'm using SQLDelight in the Kotlin/Native project (iOS & Android), and I'm looking for the best way to drop DB (all tables).
*User case: use log out from the app.* So, I was looking for a way to erase data from all tables.
So far I tried this, but I don't have access to `sqlite_master` table:

```
dropAllTables:
  PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
  DELETE FROM sqlite_master WHERE type IN ('table', 'index', 'trigger');
  PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
  VACUUM;
  PRAGMA INTEGRITY_CHECK;
```

Error: `No table found with name sqlite_master`

**What is the best way to drop all table with `SQLDeligth`?** (I want to avoid writing `DROP TABLE` fro each table)

Also, `upsert {` doesn't seems to work for me as well.. don't know how to provide `label` for it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t care about anything in the dB and want it completely cleared you can just close the connection and delete the file, next time a connection is opened it will recreate the db

Comment: In my use case, I would prefer to keep the connection and just remove data from tables. Is it possible?

Comment: No nothing like that is supported in SQLDelight

Comment: I guess it would be great to give access to the `sqlite_master `. 
Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Anstrong I've tried to delete de db file but all queries afterwards fail with `no such table`. Do I have to create a new instance of `AndroidSqliteDriver` in order to trigger automatic recreation of the db?

Comment: Room does have `clearAllTables()`
it's a valid use case. 
Wonder why it's an accepted answer.

Comment: How would I do this? I don't see anything in the APIs for deleting the database file. I could manually find the path on Android, but that doesn't help me on iOS.

Comment: `context.deleteDatabase()`

Answer (score 0):

Since I wanted to keep some immutable data in DB, the `original` solution will not work, so I did next:

1. keep a reference to the `SqlDriver`
2. Drop Required tables

```
val cursor = sqlDriver.executeQuery(
            null,
            "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' " +
                    //system tables
                    "AND name NOT LIKE '%sqlite%' " +
                    "AND name NOT LIKE '%metadata%' " +
                    "AND name NOT LIKE '%ios%' " +
                    "AND name NOT LIKE '%android%' " +
                    //immutable tables
                    "AND name != 'MySomeTalbe';",
            0
        )
        while (cursor.next()) {
            cursor.getString(0)?.let {
                sqlDriver.execute(null, "DELETE FROM $it", 0)
            }
        }
```

*Note: it is Kotlin/Native project*